# Calling topMenu for mobiles/tablets in 1.9 when moved from header block

Tags: blocks, magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, rwd, rwd-theme

I'm inserted the main navigation into the sidebar on a Magento 1.9 theme in `catalog.xml` using:-

```
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.topnav" before="cart_sidebar" template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml"/>
```

I've then commented out `topMenu` in the `header` block in `page.xml` as to not show in the header like so:-

```
    <!--<block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
        <label>Navigation Bar</label>
        <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml">
        <block type="page/html_topmenu_renderer" name="catalog.topnav.renderer" template="page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </block>-->
```

But on mobile/tablet devices in 1.9, the menu dropdown calls `topMenu` in `header.phtml` like so:-

```
    <!-- Navigation -->

    <div id="header-nav" class="skip-content">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
    </div>
```

Because `topMenu` does not exist in the header block any longer, the menu does not show.

1. Is it possible to call from the `header.phtml` instead the navigation I am using in the sidebar via the above code in `catalog.xml`.
2. Is it possible to still call `topMenu` if it doesn't exist in the `header` block or is there a workaround that would allow me to do so? Or am I restricted to just uncommenting `page.xml` `topMenu` in the `header` block and just `display: none` in CSS on screens from 771px wide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call topMenu by default and hide it for desktop and show it in smaller screen via CSS. As below:

```
.header-nav{display:none !important;}

@screen-size{max: 980px}{
    .header-nav{display:block !important;}
}
```

This would do a trick.

Comment: It's still a lot of unnecessary rendering in the frontend though unfortunately. It means printing the entire navigation menu twice on every page regardless of device. I didn't find a better answer though, so I'll mark this as the correct answer.